# Choosing the right MySQL structure for a very large time-based dataset

Tags: mysql, partitioning, bulkinsert

I have been using MySQL for the past few months and I have a good handle on smaller database structures.  Now, however, I need to decide on how to create a database that can store a large set of time oriented data in either multiple tables, or a single table.

Using a single table, I have tried partitioning it into yearly segments, however, the load times and insert times are still quite long.  Especially for searching.  The data consists of roughly 8000 reporting stations with about 300-500 reports per day (several per hour). The reports go back all the way to 1980, so easily over 120 million data points and growing.

I am not sure what may provide the best results for searching such a vast amount of data, or if it would be better to separate the data into several tables.  Each report has only a couple columns of information (time, temperature and wind).

I am sure this question has been asked many times, but any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: 120 million - bwahaha. Come back when the data set gets large.

Comment: It's kind of hard to suggest a structure/schema if you don't provide the one you're trying now.

Answer (score 2):

120M rows is big enough to conisder `PARTITIONing`.  And that it good for time-based data *if* you need to delete "old" data.  This because `DROP PARTITION` is a lot faster and less invasive than `DELETE`.

I discuss this at length [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Loading into a partitioned table should be only slightly slower (or faster in rare cases) than for a non-partitioned table.

Searching problems -- sounds like you did not index the table properly.  Some tips:

- (Usually) Put the "partition key" last in any index, if it is needed at all.
- Use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` only.
- 40 years?  40 partitions is reasonable.
- Do not partition by `station`, but *probably* use that column at the start of some indexes.
- Please show me the `CREATE TABLE` so I can be more specific in my tips.
- If you won't be deleting 'old' rows, then partitioning is *probably* a waste.  Let's see some of the queries.
- On the other hand, if you often use a date range and several stations, then you have the "2D index problem".  Partition by year; start the `PRIMARY KEY` with `station`

Do *not* use multiple tables.  This is a common Question on this forum, and the answer is always the same.

Quite possibly you need some sort of "summary table".  It might include high, low, average temp, etc for each *week*.  For, say, a multi-year temperature graph, this is clearly 7 times as fast.  More [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

Inserting only 37 rows/second should not be a problem, even on a slow HDD.  If they come in batches, then batch the `INSERTs` via multiple rows per `INSERT` statement or via `LOAD DATA`.